# Solids created from segments whose endpoints lie on two curves in space

Tags: calculus, geometry

I wasn't quite sure about how to look up for some relevant information on this problem so here it goes:

> Say we have two segments $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^3$, both with finite length and $a$ and $b$ do not lie in the same plane. A segment $v$ is an $a,b$-*segment* if it has one end in $a$ and the other end in $b$. Let $V$ be the solid that consists of all $a,b$-*segments*. Find the volume of $V$.
>
> This problem probably has a "nice enough" solution but I'm also interesting in generalizations of it, say, instead of two segments two smooth curves.

Thanks

Comment: Ya pretty much, I'm looking for a general method for, say a segment and a circle, or something

Comment: The solid consisting of all $a,b$-segments is the tetrahedron whose vertices are the  endpoints of those segments. One formula for its volume is $\frac16|a||b|h\sin\theta$, where $|a|$ and $|b|$ are the lengths of the segments, $\theta$ is the angle between direction vectors along those segments, and $h$ is the length of the segment (which I tend to call the "edge altitude") perpendicular to the lines containing those segments.